# want to Request our ISp to do rdns/ ptr modify for my Staic IP ot point to my Domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, isp, reverse-dns

we setup a mail server in our local office using **Mdaemon Mail Server** . We have a Staic ip   123.xxx.123.xxx ( as an example ) and all necessary ports (80 , 25 , 110 ) are made open .

We have a domain  abc.com which is not hosted anywhere planning host at our server only after our mail server issue solved ( at port 80 - apache http server ).  We have DNS settings made at one of free DNS service provider ( zonomi.com ).

In Zonomi - ( dns service provider) our domain abc.com has following dns records .

1. IP Addresses (A)

> abc.com                   points to   123.xxx.123.xxx
>
> mail.abc.com  points to   123.xxx.123.xxx

---

Mail Servers (MX)

> mail.abc.com  ->      abc.com

Name Servers (NS)

> ns1.zonomi.com    handles DNS for abc.com
>
> ns2.zonomi.com    handles DNS forabc.com

after finishing this settings we tried running our mail server but most mails were blocked at gmail , yahoo etc . then we come to know our  rdns( reverse dns / ptr not matching )

current  static ip    123.xxx.123.xxx  rdns check points to    123.xxx.123.xxx.vsnl.net(our ISP - vsnl ) ....

where as our forward dns look up shows

```
                  123.xxx.123.xxx   - abc.com ( or mail.abc.com ?)
```

Now  we finaly decided to ask our ISP to do necessary change in to our PTR / rDNS setting to point our domain(abc.com  or mail.abc.com ) so my question is

what are details i should need to give to my ISP to do Necessary settings on rDNS at its end

ex   like domain name , ns records details etc ?

and one more thing

we  set up  A record    abc.com   to 123.xxx.123.xxx   & mail.abc.com also to 123.xxx.123.xxx  and my mx records   mail.bac.com to handle abc.com mails

so I want to know what is exact rDNS value  **abc.com or mail.abc.com should be point against our static IP 123.xxx.123.xxx**

what should i tell to my ISP to put in rdns value abc.com or mail.abc.com ????

Answer (score 1):

- If you have domain already registered, you can write real domain - it's safe (and easier debug for possible errors)
- mail RR is or copy-paste error or definition error (missed dot?), check it
- you can ask to write any of two hostnames in reverse zone, both (for shown settings) will work - you have only pass "Paranoid IP check" for hostname (IN A  -> IN PTR  requests pair) must generate closed ring

PS: you can ever use default hostname of ISP for MX record of your domain and don't ask ISP do something - MX records of any domain can be anywhere outside domain's name-space

Comment: MX entry is a mistype as you pointed . i correctd now , any way thanks for your jelp .. i ask my ISP what you suggeseted .